# Update a value and a table with a foreign key

Tags: mysql, database

| ticketId(**) | timeExpected | timeElapsed |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 187 | 5 | 5 |
| 225 | 4 | 8 |
| 856 | 8 | 15 |
| 782 | 10 | 8 |

**primary key
*foreign key

| id(**) | (*)ticketId | beyondTime |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 187 | 0 |
| 2 | 225 | 1 |
| 3 | 856 | 1 |
| 4 | 782 | 0 |

I have to know which ticket his out of time and I have this in mind and in my database but I can't figure it out with SQL. I want to know when a ticket is out of time like the ticket number 225 is, I would like to update the other table with a binary 1 for "out of time" and 0 "good".

I don't know if I can update the "beyondTime" table when I do "timeExpected - timeElapsed" in the first table when a ticket exceed the time expected.

Comment: What are the primary keys of both tables: `id` or `ticketId`? It's not clear from the example.

Comment: What about ticket 856? It's also out of time.

Comment: Sorry I just edited that should be clear now otherwise tell me i'll correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, let's simplify the problem you're looking a solution for:

**Comparing two data field values for the rows in a table**

I believe that's basically what you're trying to do. And of course, you can make a decision based on the comparison and act accordingly like updating some values in another table if you want to.

But if all you're looking for is kind of a report, then all you need would be just a select statement equipped with the logic doing the comparison for you.

You can use SQL Case Statement for this. [Here](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_case.asp) is an easy guide if you want to take a look.

The select statement you need would be like this:

```
select ticketId, (case when timeElapsed > timeExpected then 1 else 0 end) as beyondTime from tickets
```

The result would be like this:

[image]

Two things to remember:

1. Don't get disappointed by the negative points and keep asking questions :)
2. Identify the issue you need help with and be specific with your question. I'd suggest you to update this question.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you very much yeah it's exactly what I want to do. Thank you @Alizera

Comment: Perfect! So, mark it as correct answer so others know it was the right solution to this question. You can give it a point up too if you want to :) Good luck @Zetti